# How to prove something is a metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and show that the following function defines a metric.
$f(x, y) = (0 \text{ if } x = y \text{ and } 1 \text{ if } x \neq y)$

I'm especially having trouble with the symmetry and triangle inequality steps. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can't show that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$?

Comment: @kimchilover lol I deleted my comment right away and then answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do symmetry first. We just need to show that $f(x, y)=f(y, x)$. We have

$f(x, y)= 1 * (x \not\equiv y) = 1 * (y \not\equiv x) = f(y,x)$.

Now for the triangle inequality. We have to show that for points $x,y, z$ in the space $f(x, z)\leq f(x, y) + f(y, z)$. Note that $f$ is nonnegative. So, if $x=z$, $f(x, z) =0$, so right away $0\leq f(x, y) + f(y, z)$. Otherwise $x\neq z, f(x, z) =1$. Note that it is impossible for both $x=y$ and $y=z$, since that implies that $x=z$. So at least one of $f(x, y),f(y, z)$ is 1. Since $f$ is nonnegative it follows again that $f(x, z)\leq f(x, y)+f(y, z)$, and the triangle inequality holds.

Note also that the other metric property, namely $f(x, y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y$, holds by the definition of the function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show symmetry by arguing that the definition of f is symmetric. Then the triangle inequality holds because as long as you pick a third point that isn’t the first or second point then when evaluating the inequality you get $2 \geq 1$ (again by definition of the function f).